# picking a ball has two different specifications

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve following problem, and need your help please: 
Given a box contains $n$ balls, $x$ of them are red. $y$ of the entire balls are heavy ($(n-y)$ of them are light). What's the probability of randomly picking a ball which is red and heavy.

I solve this as: $P = \frac{x}{n}. \frac{y}{n}\\ 
P=\frac{xy}{n^2}\\$

Is this correct or not?

Comment: That depends whether colour was applied independently of weight. Suppose $n=2x=2y$. If all the red balls are heavy, then the chance is 0.5. If all the red balls are light, then the chance is 0.

Comment: The colour is applied independently of weight

Comment: Then your formula is fine.

Comment: Which formula you mean? mine?

Comment: Yes, the one in your question: $\frac{xy}{n^2}$.